# How to return a csv file/Pandas DataFrame in JSON format using FastAPI?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, fastapi

I have a `.csv` file that I would like to render in a FastAPI app. I only managed to render the `.csv` file  in JSON format as follows:

```
def transform_question_format(csv_file_name):

    json_file_name = f"{csv_file_name[:-4]}.json"

    # transforms the csv file into json file
    pd.read_csv(csv_file_name ,sep=",").to_json(json_file_name)

    with open(json_file_name, "r") as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)

    return json_data

@app.get("/questions")
def load_questions():

    question_json = transform_question_format(question_csv_filename)

    return question_json
```

When I tried returning directly `pd.read_csv(csv_file_name ,sep=",").to_json(json_file_name)`, it works, as it returns a string.

How should I proceed?  I believe this is not the good way to do it.

Comment: When you say `render` - what do you mean? In general, FastAPI returns data as JSON. If you want to have a different response format, you can use one of the built-in custom response formats, or create your own: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/

Comment: Maybe check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911336/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dumps-and-json-load, but so far it seems good

Comment: I am ok with JSON output but problem is that i need this intermediate step of creating an output JSON file and then load it. Obviously i cannot import csv, transform and load in one step. 

thanks  for the links. It clarifies a bit the process.

Comment: If you don't give a filename to `to_json` a JSON string is returned directly. You can then pair this with `return Response(content=json_str, media_type="application/json")` to return the string directly from FastAPI with a JSON header. Would that work? (you can also give a File-like object and get output written to that, so something like `StringIO` should work as well)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The below shows four different ways of returning the data stored in a `.csv` file/Pandas DataFrame (for solutions without using Pandas DataFrame, have a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804)). Related answers on how to efficiently return a large dataframe can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) as well.

#### Option 1

The first option is to convert the file data into `JSON` and then parse it into a `dict`. You can optionally change the orientation of the data using the `orient` parameter in the [`.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method.

**Note:** Better **not to use** this option. See **Updates** below.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import pandas as pd
import json

app = FastAPI()
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

def parse_csv(df):
    res = df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(res)
    return parsed
    
@app.get("/questions")
def load_questions():
    return parse_csv(df)
```

- **Update 1**: Using [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method would be a better option, as it would return a `dict` directly, instead of converting the DataFrame into JSON (using `df.to_json()`) and then that JSON string into `dict` (using `json.loads()`), as described earlier. Example:

  ```py
  @app.get("/questions")
  def load_questions():
      return df.to_dict(orient="records")
  ```
- **Update 2**: When using [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method and returning the `dict`, FastAPI, behind the scenes, [automatically converts](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/) that return value into `JSON` using the Python standard `json.dumps()`, after converting it into JSON-compatible data first, using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), and then putting that JSON-compatible data inside of a `JSONResponse` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details). Thus, to avoid that extra processing, you could still use the [`.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method, but this time, put the `JSON` string in a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response) and return it directly, as shown below:

  ```py
  from fastapi import Response

  @app.get("/questions")
  def load_questions():
      return Response(df.to_json(orient="records"), media_type="application/json")
  ```

#### Option 2

Another option is to return the data in `string` format, using [`.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) method.

```py
@app.get("/questions")
def load_questions():
    return df.to_string()
```

#### Option 3

You could also return the data as an `HTML` table, using [`.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method.

```py
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

@app.get("/questions")
def load_questions():
    return HTMLResponse(content=df.to_html(), status_code=200)
```

#### Option 4

Finally, you can always return the `file` as is using FastAPI's [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse).

```py
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

@app.get("/questions")
def load_questions():
    return FileResponse(path="file.csv", filename="file.csv")
```

Comment: You can avoid json dump/load sequence by just calling `DataFrame.to_dict()` instead.

Comment: @Chris by the way i saw you updated with `async`, and of course i have seen this into the documentation. In such a case would it be to allow several users to query the API at the same time ?

Comment: @pac You could also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71188190/17865804) answer, if it helps clarify things about `async` for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I find that the package [jsonpickle](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpickle/) provides a simple solution to the issue of returning a DataFrame or Numpy ndarray to the client side.

On the server side:

```
import jsonpickle.ext.pandas as jsonpickle_pandas
from jsonpickle.pickler import Pickler

jsonpickle_pandas.register_handlers()

@app.post("/question")
def answer_question():
    df = pd.DataFrame(...)
    p = Pickler()
    # convert the dataframe to a json-compatible dictionary
    response = p.flatten(df)
    # let FastAPI do the json conversion
    return response
```

On the client side:

```
from jsonpickle.unpickler import Unpickler
import jsonpickle.ext.pandas as jsonpickle_pandas
jsonpickle_pandas.register_handlers()

response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/question/")
res = response.json()

u = Unpickler()
df = u.restore(res)
```

The advantage of this solution is that Pickler/Unpickler handles dates and periods. In fact, it will turn any object into a dictionary of jsonable items, up to a user-specified depth.